# Android TextView using style attribute doesn't stay in one line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I'm pretty new to Android, and trying to define a style for my layout.
My layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/background_test"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/transparent_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/TitleScrollable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        style="@style/SubtitleScrollable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

In my style.xml:

```
<style name="Title" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5">
    <item name="android:text">Long Long Title</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryDark</item>
</style>
<style name="TitleScrollable" parent="Title">
    <item name="singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:marqueeRepeatLimit">marquee_forever</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
</style>
```

But my title is still wrapping to next lines.
When i use this style elsewhere it works fine.
When adding `maxLines=1` in the layout it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried using `<item name="android:maxLines">1</item>` instead of `<item name="maxLines">1</item>`?

Comment: I can't believe i wasted half a day on such a stupid mistake. Thank you! I only added that as a try to fix the problem, because singleLine worked so far..